# dynamic selection screen based on the number of records in Z-table

Tags: dynamic, parameters, abap, sap-selection-screens

I've a Z-table which has certain number of records for
now say 15 records. Using these 15 records and based
on 2 fields say group and position I've to create 15
check boxes in selection screen dynamically. If in
future the Z-table records are updated to 25 or 30
records . I need 25-30 check boxes in selection screen
dynamically with out change in the code..
Please help with this problem...

Comment: As you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is there an upper limit to the number of check boxes you need?

If there is it's not that hard to only show the number you need. If there is no upper limit then it becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: As of now there is no upper limit. Assume upper limit as 50 and help me with solution.

Comment: In Selection Screen ? Remember, selection screens are usually "prior to a selection" processed. You might inspect the "TIMESTAMP-EVENTS", which an selection screen offers, in order to read the z-table in an event like "AT-SELECTION-SCREEN-OUTPUT". INITIALIZATION or LOAD-OF-PROGRAM. But then I do not know how to proceed. I would start with a real program, which does all the stuff You need in an alv-grid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion. Instead of generating checkboxes from your table lines you could easily populate a dropdown menu or better yet an ALV grid with the values from your table, which can then in turn be selected by the user. Evaluating the user selection programmatically will be easy enough. Plus you won't have to worry about varying dynpro sizes as your table grows further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with an upper limit of 10 dynamical check boxes on the selection screen with dynamic descriptions and value assignment.

```
REPORT ztest_check_boxes.

DATA: g_num_check_boxes TYPE i,
      g_num_cb_shown    TYPE i,
      g_first_time      TYPE abap_bool VALUE abap_true.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <cb>   TYPE flag,
               <text> TYPE any.

PARAMETERS: px_01 AS CHECKBOX MODIF ID cb,
            px_02 AS CHECKBOX MODIF ID cb,
            px_03 AS CHECKBOX MODIF ID cb,
            px_04 AS CHECKBOX MODIF ID cb,
            px_05 AS CHECKBOX MODIF ID cb,
            px_06 AS CHECKBOX MODIF ID cb,
            px_07 AS CHECKBOX MODIF ID cb,
            px_08 AS CHECKBOX MODIF ID cb,
            px_09 AS CHECKBOX MODIF ID cb,
            px_10 AS CHECKBOX MODIF ID cb.

INITIALIZATION.

  " Determine the number of checkboxes to show,
  " for simplicity I just hard coded this
  g_num_check_boxes = 3.


AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.

  g_num_cb_shown = 0.

  LOOP AT SCREEN.

    IF screen-group1 EQ 'CB'.
      " This will trigger on the check box
      " as well as their descriptions

      IF g_num_cb_shown LT g_num_check_boxes.
        " Need to display this check box
        CASE screen-group3.
          WHEN 'PAR'.
            " This is the check box
            " you can set the value here dynamically.
            " Should only be done once
            IF g_first_time EQ abap_true.
              ASSIGN (screen-name) TO <cb>.
              IF ( g_num_cb_shown MOD 2 ) EQ 0.
                <cb> = 'X'.
              ENDIF.
            ENDIF.

          WHEN 'TXT'.
            " This is the text, you could set this with
            " data from your database table
            ASSIGN (screen-name) TO <text>.
            <text> = `Checkbox ` && g_num_cb_shown.

            " TXT comes after PAR, so we should do this here
            ADD 1 TO g_num_cb_shown.

        ENDCASE.

      ELSE.
        " Need to hide this check box
        screen-active = '0'.
        MODIFY SCREEN.

      ENDIF. " Display?

    ENDIF. " Check box?

  ENDLOOP. " SCREEN

  g_first_time = abap_false.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  ...
```